# Show a div on first page load only

Tags: javascript

I have a div that serves of container for a css animation that appears over the entire website's home page... a text and background that opens like curtains, revealing the website under it. It's like an intro landing page. The thing is I need it to appear only on first page load. I don't want it to appear on page refresh or if someone navigates thru the site and comes back to home page.

Can someone please show me how I would have to code this because I've search a lot on the web and didn't find any clear explanations for my particular case.

Here is the code for the div:

```html
<div id="landContainer">
<div class="left-half" id="leftP"><article class="leftPanel"><img id="SloganLeft" src="Decouvrez.svg"></article></div>
<div class="right-half" id="RightP"><article class="rightPanel"><img id="SloganRight" src="Atteignez.svg"></article></div>
</div>
```

So the div I must display only on first page load would be the one with the ID landContainer, that contains a couple of other divs.

Since I'm new to this type of coding, I would need a complete example of the code I need to use with my div.

---

For Ian... here is the content of my index.html file...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Landing page v2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="landing.css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="landContainer">
  <div class="left-half" id="leftP">
    <article class="leftPanel"><img id="SloganLeft" src="Decouvrez.svg"></article>
  </div>
  <div class="right-half" id="RightP">
    <article class="rightPanel"><img id="SloganRight" src="Atteignez.svg"></article>
  </div>
</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
        <script scr="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var isExists = localStorage.getItem("pageloadcount");
if (isExists != 'undefined') { $("#landContainer").hide();
} 
  localStorage.setItem("pageloadcount", "1");
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use a cookie or local storage. The first time they hit the page, check if they have the cookie, if not show the div and then set the cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Landing page v2</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="landing.css" media="screen" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $( document ).ready(function() {
             if (localStorage.getItem("pageloadcount")) { $("#landContainer").hide();
         } 
             localStorage.setItem("pageloadcount", "1");
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="landContainer">
         <div class="left-half" id="leftP">
            <article class="leftPanel"><img id="SloganLeft" src="Decouvrez.svg"></article>
         </div>
         <div class="right-half" id="RightP">
            <article class="rightPanel"><img id="SloganRight" src="Atteignez.svg"></article>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aaaah! That works! Thank you very much Jayesh! :)

Now I'm gonna study it to learn.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    var isExists = localStorage.getItem("pageloadcount");
if (isExists != 'undefined') { $("#landContainer").hide();
} 
  localStorage.setItem("pageloadcount", "1");
});
```

```html
<div id="landContainer">
  <div class="left-half" id="leftP">
    <article class="leftPanel"><img id="SloganLeft" src="Decouvrez.svg"></article>
  </div>
  <div class="right-half" id="RightP">
    <article class="rightPanel"><img id="SloganRight" src="Atteignez.svg"></article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please show me how you would code this storage javascript? I'm new with all of this and I really need this function for an active project.

Comment: you can set localstorage when your page is loaded first time by localStorage.setItem("pageloadcount", "1"); Then to access you can use localStorage.getItem(“pageloadcount”); if it is "1" that means your page is loaded once.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob but, could you show me an actual complete example of how you would code it with my divs shown in my first post please?

Comment: Thanks for your patience and understanding! ^^

Comment: I hope this code will help
var isExists=localStorage.getItem("pageloadcount");
if(isExists=='undefined') {//do what you want on first page load}
else{
localStorage.setItem("pageloadcount", "1"); 
}

Comment: And if in {//do what you want on first page load} I want to display the div with the id of landContainer, how would I write it down between those {} ?

Comment: Oh! OK, sorry! ^^

So, if I use you code, I get this error in Chrome console : (index):8 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

And when I refresh the page, the div still appears.

Comment: that means you need to include jquery in your code. you can include it by <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hmmm... I've put your exact jsfiddle code in my index.html file and still get the error

Comment: Not sure how can i help you on this now. Can you share your index.html file?

Comment: How could I share it? Is there a way to attach a file in my first post?

Comment: Updated my first post (at the end) with my index.html code  :)

Comment: Edited my answer again with modification to your code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use session through which you can determine if its a new request or old.
Server side session will be best here

Comment: Could you please show me a complete example of how to code this with my divs shown in my first post? I'm very new to javascript. Thanks in advance!  :)

Comment: I am talking about server side not javascript. You can use php session If your server side language is php otherwise any other